# correct word for an object being worked on

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, word-usage

If an object is being worked on, changed, corrected, ect. in some way, what would you call that object? 
Someone asked if I'm looking for a noun or adjective ... great question ... looking for a noun!

Comment: Mutable, volatile.

Comment: the project focus

Comment: May be a "lean product". (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lean_product_development)

Comment: Are you looking for a *noun* or an *adjective*?

Comment: The object you are working on could be called a *project.* Object = thrown against, project = thrown at.

Comment: The object is a _subject_: 4. a person or thing that undergoes experiment, analysis, treatment, etc [Collins]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Workpiece" is the term used in manufacturing and woodworking trades.

Answer (score 0):

If something can be changed or changes, it can be said to be:

- [Mutable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutable)
- [Variable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variable)
- [Volatile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volatile)
- [Inconstant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inconstant)

Something which is not final, i.e. is being worked on and corrected, can be called a [draft](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draft).

Comment: These mean that it's capable of being worked on, not that it _is_ being worked on. E.g. a lump of clay just sitting in the corner is mutable, but it's not being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to the OP is opinion-based, IMO-

> - If object is being worked up on- it's a work in progress, the object    is a [piece of work.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/piece+of+work)
> - If it's changed, the object is a new product altogether.
> - If it's corrected, the object is an updated product.